# Is there software that allows multiple users to simultaneously and independently share a personal computer running Mac Os?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, xorg, multiple-users

Like [BeTwin](http://www.thinsoftinc.com/product_pc_sharing_betwin.aspx). For example, I have Macbook Pro with one Mini DisplayPort (for additional monitor) and two USB port (for additional mouse and keyboard).
How can i implement it on Mac OS Snow Leopard?

Comment: I think the best you can do is get the cheapest possible computer and use Lion's new multi-user screen sharing.

Comment: The snow leopard [EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx106.pdf) does not expressly prohibit multiple users on the same computer, so from the legal side this question is valid. And Lion's [EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx107.pdf) expressly permits multiple users and does not expressly prohibit multiple simultaneous users.